# Where to Find Screenwriters?

Tags: screenwriting

I'm currently searching for a new screenplay. So I'm looking for forums/pages where I can find writers.

They can or maybe should be non-professional, because the movie is micro-low budget to low budget movie, we don't have the capacity to get an pro.

Do you know of such forums which could help me find a writer or already existing story?

Comment: Hi Timothy, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We require practical, answerable questions about writing which are likely to help others in the future. Please see our help center and take our tour to see what kinds of questions we answer here.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, asking artists, amateur or professional, "Where do I find someone who will make your kind of art for me for little to no money?" is, at the very least, impolite.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Sure. I know that it isn't good to ask people to do it for dree. But fact is, I can't afford that much. They wouldn't do it for nothing. I can effort about 300$. I think for a non-pro writer this is a nice small additional income. They don't need to write a full script. A short story is enough that I could finish. Or even an allready written story. So do you have an idea for an forum?

Comment: @TimothyLukasH. Why don't you google something like "screenwriting forum jobs"? Or you could post job offers in craigslist and other classified advertisements websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try local writers' groups. My writing group has been approached in the past by local people who are making low budget movies and want stories / writers, and some of them have been quite pleased by the idea of having their writing put into screen pictures.

Comment: That's actually a good idea. I will look if there is anything of that kind around here :) Thanks